# Eclipse: Run a JavaScript program many times to make it work

Tags: javascript, eclipse

A few days ago I started learning to program in JavaScript, for this purpose I downloaded a version of Eclipse dedicated to JavaScript ("eclipse-javascript-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip").
Everything is fine with Eclipse for Java, while with Eclipse for JavaScript I have the following problem:

when I write a program in JavaScript and launch it all is fine, when however I EDIT the program and try to run the new program very often Eclipse executes the OLD program for me, to run the NEW program I have to click on "Run > Run As > Run on Server" to, at least, twice (often even four or five times).

Can someone help me?

Comment: Indigo is from 2011-2012. It's not the version to use to learn modern JavaScript. Use the current release: 2020-03 , from https://https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual studio code or Adobe Dreamwaver. It is very simple and experimenting

https://www.adobe.com/mena_ar/products/dreamweaver/free-trial-download.html

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Imran AKKI

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as IDE I would like to use Eclipse, which I have previously used to program in Java, and so I already know.
Can anyone please explain to me how to write a program that displays "Hello World" with "Eclipse JavaScript 2020-03" ?

Answer (score 0):

From "Eclipse Marketplace" I installed the "Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.17" plug-in on "Eclipse 2020-03".
Now I can create a "Static Web Project" and run JavaScript programs, but I always have THE SAME problem that I had with "Eclipse Indigo", to run a NEW program I have to launch the NEW program five or six times (only now everything is noticeably slower).
Sometimes an error window appeared to me, I attach the screenshot.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfhJe.png)